# How to garrison troops in Medieval II: Total War?

Tags: medieval-2-total-war

I was playing campaign mode, and it says that you don't have to pay the troops' upkeep if they're garrisoned. I'd really like the money, but the problem is, I can't figure out how to do this. I'm looking for some button, but I just don't see it. A picture would be helpful, but not necessary.

Also, is there some catch to this? Do you need some building, can only a certain number of units be garrisoned, can you not move them anymore afterwards, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You garrison troops by simply moving them into a settlement. It depends on the unit for free upkeep whether it can produce them. Castles cannot do it for free.

Comment: Okay, I think I get it then. If troops are in a town, and the town can make troops of that type, then they're garrisoned, and I don't have to pay upkeep?

Comment: Yup that is correct.

Comment: The most common way this works is with militia, which makes it cheaper to defend your towns properly.  I believe the garrisoned units also show up as a different background color (blue instead of gray).

Comment: I downvoted because the answer is incorrect; only some units can be garrisoned and there's another constraint required.

Answer (score 1):

In the base game, two conditions need to be fulfilled for free upkeep:

- The unit needs to be militia. It should say so in the unit's name, e.g. "Spear militia".
- The settlement needs to be able to produce that unit. You can't garrison Spear militia in a settlement that cannot produce Spear militia.

Finally, there is also:

- You only have a limited number of free upkeep slots (which depends on which structures you have constructed). You can't make 20 Spear militia and garrison them in a town; you can only garrison (if I remember right) up to six, and then only in a huge city.